# C++ calling pure virtual function from non virtual function in base class

Tags: c++, linker-errors, clang++, virtual-functions

I am aware that you can / should not call virtual functions in the constructor and that a pure virtual destructor is not possible.

I have two classes, Base and Child.

Base has a pure virtual function and a normal function which calls the virtual one.

```
// base.h
class Base {
public:
    virtual int foo() const = 0;
    int bar() const;
};

// base.cpp
#include "base.h"
int Base::bar() const {
    return this->foo()*3;
}
```

Child implements the virtual function.

```
// child.h
#include "base.h"
class Child : public Base {
public:
    int foo() const;
};

// child.cpp
#include "child.h"
int Child::foo() const {
    return 5;
}
```

I then create child object and call bar, which is defined in the base.

```
// main.cpp
#include "child.h"
...
Child c;
std::cout << c.bar();
...
```

The clang compiler then gives me a linker error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Base::bar() const", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "vtable for Child", referenced from:
      Child::Child() in main.cpp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This does not make sense to me because as far as I am aware there is one pure virtual member function foo which has been defined by the child class. As far as I can see bar is not marked as virtual and so should have a symbol defined. Is is somehow transitively virtual?

Where am I going wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(inheritance)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(inheritance ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

EDIT 2: SOLUTION
as per @dasblinkenlight 's answer the source files must be compiled together so line 6 of the last code block must be changed to

```
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp base.cpp child.cpp)
```

Comment: How if at all did you link your program?

Comment: Works fine as is https://ideone.com/nqjoCM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am aware that you can / should not call virtual functions in the constructor and that a pure virtual destructor is not possible.

Declaring a function pure virtual does not mean that you cannot provide an implementation for it. This applies to destructors as well:

```
struct Foo {
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
    ...
};
Foo::~Foo() {
    ... // Implement destructor
}
```

> The clang compiler then gives me a linker error
>
> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "Base::bar() const", referenced from:
> ```

This usually happens when you incorrectly compile your classes one-by-one, and then do not link them properly. The compiler has a simple way to compile all classes together, and link the results, as follows:

```
g++ base.cpp child.cpp main.cpp
```

Note that you need to include headers for the classes in their implementation files, for example

```
#include "base.h"

int Base::bar() {
    return this->foo()*3;
}
```

Make sure that you fix any errors that come up in the process (hint: the above will produce an error).

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight I am using cmake, see my edit to the question. Perhaps I need to add all the source files to the makefile rather than just the main.cpp.

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo, "const" is missed in Base::bar function, and then it is different with function signature declared in Base class.

```
// base.cpp
int Base::bar() const {
    return this->foo()*3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ravin. (NB: this does not fix the compiler error)

Comment: I compiled your code with g++-7.2 successfully, and it works exactly after fixing the typo.

Comment: Ok thanks ravin, I am using cmake, I have added my CMakeLists.txt to the question.

Comment: Thank you for correcting my typo. It seems that the problem was my cmake was not compiling the classes together because I configured it incorrectly as per @dasblinkenlight 's answer. As this was the core issue I will mark his answer as the correct answer but I appreciate you catching my other error.